# Rails & Pre-existing MySQL Database: Is there an easy way to integrate database structure into Active Record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dbmigrate

I have a pre-existing MySQL database with naming conventions far from Rails conventions. Is there any option, other than manually making each model, to get all the database information ready for Rails? Obviously scaffold won't do any good here.

It seems like something someone might have written a script to automate, but I wouldn't have the first clue where to look. Google didn't turn anything up on quick inspection.

Thanks!

PS- Just to clarify, I'm stuck with the database structure. I just need to give Rails the necessary information to interact with the MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> set_table_name :name

to make it such that the table name don't match the model class

> belongs_to :other_model, :foreign_key => :column_name, :primary_key =>
>   :column_name

to force the relationship ids

(gets REALLY annoying, but if you must)

Comment: Yeah. If I must, I'll do that. Like you said though, with the number of tables and cols, that will get old VERY fast...

Comment: Rails 3.2 and up changed this to:

self.table_name = :name